# How do I get around or rectify what I think is a version issue between OpenLayers and proj4js?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, proj4js, wfs

I am trying to get rid of a 404 console error on a page with a map that includes many complex features. The 404 error says that projCode/merc.js cannot be found.

The cshtml file for the page includes the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/proj4js-combined.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/proj4js-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/proj4js.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/ol.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Maps/toGeoJson.js"></script>
```

As far as I can tell (I did not write this code), OpenLayers causes proj4js to reference merc.js, but merc.js does not exist as a file. In fact, the comments in the file 'proj4js-combined.js' suggest to me that the contents of merc.js are now inside 'proj4js-combined.js', which is why I think there is some version clash between OpenLayers and proj4js.

Even though the 404 appears as soon as the scripts are loaded, OpenLayers is actually used for only one thing on the entire page: when loading a WFS layer that returns XML data, toGeoJson.js uses ol.js to convert that data into json if its data type is kml, but it uses OpenLayers.js if the data type is gml2, gml3, or text/xml with a subtype of gml/3.1.1.

I don't see a version number inside the proj4js.js file, but the OpenLayers.js file is version 2.13.1.

So what is the simplest way for me to get rid of the console error? Should I upgrade OpenLayers*, upgrade proj4js*, change how my code calls OpenLayers to fix the problem, or get rid of OpenLayers entirely and use something else for the conversion?

(*)  I don't know which of these would need the upgrade because I don't know which is older without access to a proj4js version number.

Comment: You should need only one of those scripts, using 3 different ones together could cause conflicts.  OpenLayers 2 examples used proj4js version 1.1.0 but later versions can be used with a patch as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323559/102658  You can download from or link directly to the CDN to be sure of what you are ujsing https://cdnjs.com/libraries/proj4js/1.1.0